# Order after exponents in R

Tags: r, string, list, function, sorting

I have different strings in R containing a function: function <- "2x^{2}+6x^{5}+x^{4}+2"
I need the output ordered after the exponents starting with the highest, so: "6x^{5}+x^{4}+2x^{2}+2"

I thought about writing a function splitting the string after the "^" then take the number, sort it and put it together again. But it seems a bit complicated. Is there a way of just sorting after the numbers that come after the ^ sign? Maybe that I create a list splitting in subterms and then ordering after the exponents within that list.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see another way than parsing and splitting the string yourself as you described. Using only base R functions, you can use a helper function like

```
sort_by_exp <- function(ex) {
  parts <- strsplit(ex, "+", fixed = TRUE)
  sapply(parts, function(x) {
    matches <- regexpr("\\^\\{(\\d+)\\}", x, perl=TRUE)
    cstart <- attr(matches, "capture.start")
    clen <- attr(matches, "capture.length")
    exp <- as.numeric(ifelse(cstart>-1, substr(x, cstart, cstart+clen-1), "0"))
    paste(x[order(exp, decreasing=TRUE)], collapse="+")    
  })
}
```

Which you can use on one or more expressions

```
sort_by_exp(c("2x^{2}+6x^{5}+x^{4}+2", "x^{1}+x^{9}"))
[1] "6x^{5}+x^{4}+2x^{2}+2" 
[2] "x^{9}+x^{1}"
```